# How to integrate $1/t$ using substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I integrate $1/t$ from $1$ to $4$

Comment: You could just find an antiderivative and apply the FTC. Do you really have to use $u$ substitution?

Comment: Make the substitution $u = \frac{1}{t}$, har har.

Comment: You can do a u-sub by letting 1/t = v  But you will still get a similar integral back (Oh joy!!). So do you know the anti derivative of 1/t ?? That will do it in my opinion

Comment: I got 3/t for my answer.

Comment: This is a definite integral. The answer will not depend on $t$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\frac{d}{dx}(\log(x))= \frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

Using MITjanitor's hint, we know that $$\frac{d}{dt}(\log(t))= \frac{1}{t},$$ so we can conclude that $\int_1^4\frac1t dt = \log(t)|^4_1 = \log(4)-\log(1)=\log(4)$.

The integral equals $\log(4)$ because $\log(1)=0$.

Also, this is a duplicate from your very own [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366563/how-to-integrate-1-x).